# What @Json annotation to use for forgein key

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

I need an annotation that will only return certain Object properties or only forgein key 
User:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;
    ...
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private Set<Log> logs=new HashSet<>();
```

Logs:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long logsId;
    ...
    @JsonProperty<--------
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;
    ...
```

I am using `@JsonProperty` but it returns a whole object with vulnerable data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @jsonignore annotation for the properties that you don't want to be retrieved. If you have too much data to be annotated, I would suggest you to move those attributes to a single class and have a property on that while it's being annotated with @jsonignore. Mainly this annotation is used to remove cyclic data returned with foreign keys.

Comment: I completly didn't thought of that even though i used it, I was focused to much on ignoring it inside log file instead of user. Thank you!